# Can't see the data after I inserted the data to firebase real-time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Button getBtn, sendBtn;
EditText edtTxt, getTxt;

FirebaseDatabase DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference hisRef = DB.getReference("history");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_corp_history);

    getBtn = findViewById(R.id.getbtn);
    sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);

    edtTxt = findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
    getTxt = findViewById(R.id.gettxt);


}

public void sendDataToDB(View view) {
    String s = edtTxt.getText().toString();
    hisRef.setValue(s);

}

public void getDataFromDB(View view) {
    hisRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String val = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            getTxt.setText(val);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I am basically trying to create a history branch on my json tree and assign its value to the value that comes from the edit text field. After inserting the data I can see the sent data on my other edit text field but it doesn't appear on the real time database also when I refresh the app getBtn doesn't work. How can I fix this issue with firebase real-time database

I added the firebase from the tools section I don't know if it causes a problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so it helps if you can try/check more things yourself. For example: 1) is there any relevant log message written when you try to write to the database? 2) what happens if you `hisRef.setValue(true);` (or any other *hardcoded* value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest update when connecting to Firebase from the Tools menu, **SHA1** does not add this dairectly must be add manually.

Checking the rules in the database like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```